# Python Logging to Different File name than Intended

Tags: python, logging

So I am trying to log data from my scripts. I also have a handler program that is used to run the scripts. But when I run the file from the main. it logs the data in a different program's log file. Been trying this for quite some time. any help will be appreciated. attaching my Code Below

```
import logging
    
rfh = handlers.RotatingFileHandler(filename='logs/Binance.log',
                                   maxBytes=2.3 * 1024 * 1024, 
                                   backupCount= 1,
                                   encoding=None,
                                   delay=0)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', handlers=[rfh])

    def write_logs(log):
    logging.info(log)
write_logs("This is a test")
```

This is one module. I have multiple like these. almost the same code.
Now for the main program.

```
from sockets import bitfinex
from sockets import binance
from sockets import bybit
from sockets import coinbase
from sockets import coinflex
from sockets import cryptocom
from sockets import ftx
from sockets import gateio
from sockets import gemini
from sockets import huobi
from sockets import poloniex


def selection():
    print("List of Exchanges")
    print("1. Binance")
    print("2. Bitfinex")
    print("3. Bybit")
    print("4. Coinbase")
    print("5. Coinflex")
    print("6. Crypto.com")
    print("7. FTX")
    print("8. Gate.IO")
    print("9. Gemini")
    print("10. Huobi")
    print("11. Poloniex")
    choice = int(input("Exchange No: "))

    if choice == 1:
        print("Connecting to Binance")
        binance.start()
    elif choice == 2:
        print("Connecting to Bitfinex")
        bitfinex.start()
    elif choice == 3:
        print("Connecting to Bybit")
        bybit.start()
    elif choice == 4:
        print("Connecting to Coinbase")
        coinbase.start()
    elif choice == 5:
        print("Connecting to Coinflex")
        coinflex.start()
    elif choice == 6:
        print("Connecting to Crypto.com")
        cryptocom.start()
    elif choice == 7:
        print("Connecting to FTX")
        ftx.start()
    elif choice == 8:
        print("Connecting to Gate.IO")
        gateio.start()
    elif choice == 9:
        print("Connecting to Gemini")
        gemini.start()
    elif choice == 10:
        print("Connecting to Huobi")
        huobi.start()
    elif choice == 11:
        print("Connecting to Poloniex")
        poloniex.start()
    else:
        print("Invalid Choice")


selection()
```

When I try to run from the main program. It writes to file 2: Bitfinex.log no matter which one I try to run. the individual programs work fine.
Any Help will be appreciated.
:

Comment: One of your imports is initializing `logging` and that is preempting your call to  `basicConfig()`. Set up your own logging before doing the other imports. Yes, I know your linter will complain that it's not PEP-8 but the linter hasn't read the documentation  for `logging`.

Comment: Please try to reduce your problem to a [mre].

Comment: Done. Removed all the useless code and only left whats related to logging. @tripleee

Comment: @BoarGules, So should I move all lines from program 1 above all other imports?

Comment: Well, what I would do is put the code concerned in its own module `mylogging`  and do `import mylogging` at or near the top of all of my other modules. That way, refactoring into smaller modules carries less risk. But that's a style thing. Who gets to initialize `logging` is what's important, and your code has to take charge and do it first, to do what you expect. It's sometimes easy to forget that `import` is an executable statement and order sometimes matters quite a lot.